# Run node server on boot

Tags: boot-issues, node.js

I am trying to run a node app on boot. The script runs ok from the command line, I can stop and start it but when I try to do it on boot I get an error as if the script were reading the node_app.js line by line.

Here is my script my_node_server:

```
#! /bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          skeleton
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Example initscript
# Description:       This file should be used to construct scripts to be
#                    placed in /etc/init.d.
### END INIT INFO


# Some things that run always

APP_DIR="/home/pi/node_app_folder"

NODE_APP="node_app.js"

LOG_FILE="/home/pi/my_node_server.log"

PID_FILE="/home/pi/my_node_server.pid"

NODE_EXEC=$(which node)


# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting script my_node_server "
    echo "Check log in /home/pi/my_node_server.log"

    echo "" > "$LOG_FILE"
    echo "" > "$PID_FILE"

    "$NODE_EXEC" "$APP_DIR/$NODE_APP" > "$LOG_FILE" 2>&1 &

    echo $! > "$PID_FILE"
    echo  "my_node_server is working with pid: $(cat $PID_FILE)" | tee "$LOG_FILE"
    echo "Check pid in /home/pi/my_node_server.pid"
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping script my_node_server" | tee -a "$LOG_FILE"
    PID="$(cat "$PID_FILE")"
    echo killing PID: "$PID"
    kill "$PID"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/my_node_server {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

It also works on the command line, from both pi and root users:

```
APP_DIR="/home/pi/node_app_folder"

NODE_APP="node_app.js"

NODE_PROGRAM=$(which node)

"$NODE_PROGRAM" "$APP_DIR/$NODE_APP" 2>&1
```

Why does it not do it at boot time? I have done:

```
sudo update-rc.d my_node_server defaults
```

By the way my shell is bash:

```
$ echo $0
/bin/bash
```

If I replace

`"$NODE_EXEC" "$APP_DIR/$NODE_APP" > "$LOG_FILE" 2>&1 &`

for

```
/home/pi/my-node-dir/bin/node /home/pi/node_app.js > "$LOG_FILE" 2>&1 &
```

it works ok.

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could confirm this by logging the value of `$NODE_EXEC` somewhere, but I think it is probably not what you think it is.

```
NODE_EXEC=$(which node)
```

It certainly won't be `/home/pi/my-node-dir/bin/node`, because that path isn't in $PATH.  If there's a node in $PATH, it would use that.  If there isn't, that variable will be "which: no node in (...)".

You could add to path at beginning:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/pi/my-node-dir/bin
```

Or you could just hardcode `$NODE_EXEC` to the value you actually want.

Comment: Of course `/home/pi/my-node-dir/bin` is in my $PATH, otherwise it wouldn't run from the cli. And it is in the $PATH for pi user and root user as well.

`$ which node`
produces
`/home/pi/my-node-dir/bin/node`

Comment: It's not in `$PATH` when that script is run by [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), unless you've specifically configured the system to put it there.  Again, these are things you could check very simply by just *logging the values to a file to confirm they are what you **think** they are*.  This is basic debugging 101.  If you can't be bothered to do that, there is no help anyone can give you.

Comment: The point here is: $PATH is not set to include your local path by the time init runs the script, so you cannot rely on `which node` to find node. You need to either put node in a directory that is in a default available path (`/opt/bin` perhaps?) or explicitly put the path to node in your script.

Comment: As @goldilocks and Phil_B remarked at boot time the $PATH variable hasn't been set yet. 
In the end I hardcoded the $NODE_EXEC variable to my node installation path.